# How to pick a random number for a list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, random

I want to pick a random number from a list of integers in a MySQL Stored Procedure. This list is generated from another function using some calculations.

Example:

`[41,69,9,31,10,33,13,73,20,62,21,58,22,39]`

I tried the `RAND()` function but they are dependent on constant min, max, and step values it seems. Any help would be great.

Note:
This list of numbers is not always constant, so they do not have constant min, max, or step values.

Comment: mysql has no way, to handle that easy, so it would be beter to get the data in a normalized fashion and use simple sql commands

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions that can be used. Try using `elt()` function.

````
[41,69,9,31,10,33,13,73,20,62,21,58,22,39]```
````